# Upadate mysql database text using a query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

We currently have a database that has stored over 100,000 records of data over the years however in a structure that does not work anymore.

There is a field in the table called youtube_video

It has been storing all of the embed YouTube videos like this:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/3mHuu5NklOs?rel=0
http://www.youtube.com/embed/3mHuu5NklOs
```

We need to change it to:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3mHuu5NklOs
```

Is there a way to write a query that makes this change with a single query?

Comment: MySQL has [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html). Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use REGEXP_REPLACE :

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
    youtube_video,
    '^http://www.youtube.com/embed/([^?]+).*',
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\1'
) FROM mytable
```

Regex breakdown :

- `^` : start of string
- `http://www.youtube.com/embed/` : constant string part
- `([^?]+)` : as many consecutive characters as possible others than a question mark ; the surrounding parentheses capture that part of the string, and make it available as `\1` in the second argument to `REGEXP_REPLACE()`
- `.*` : anything (until end of string)

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cYesbAB9ntKoY6CLXJ1oQK/2)** returns :

```
| youtube_video                                  | new_youtube_video                           |
| ---------------------------------------------- | ------------------------------------------- |
| http://www.youtube.com/embed/3mHuu5NklOs?rel=0 | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3mHuu5NklOs |
| http://www.youtube.com/embed/3mHuu5NklOs       | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3mHuu5NklOs |
```

If needed, you can easily turn this into an `UPDATE` :

```
UPDATE mytable
SET youtube_video = REGEXP_REPLACE(
    youtube_video,
    '^http://www.youtube.com/embed/([^?]+).*',
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\1'
);
```